# Issue with Passing and Retrieving Variables in Playwright Tests for globalTeardown.ts

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I'm encountering a problem with passing and retrieving variables within my Playwright tests. I'm trying to maintain a count of passed and failed tests, and I'm using environment variables to store these counts throughout my test suite. However, I'm facing challenges when trying to access and update these variables within teardown.

The issue seems to be related to how I'm setting and accessing the environment variables. I've tried different approaches, including using the process.env object to store and retrieve the counts, as well as using a helper class to manage the counts. However, none of these approaches have yielded the expected results.

```
let passCount = 0;
let failCount = 0;

test.afterEach(async ({ helper }, testInfo) => {
  logger.info(`Dashboard: ${currRecord.dashboard_name} is ${testInfo.status}`);
  if (testInfo.status !== "passed") {
    helper.sendFailureNofitication(process.env.app_job_notify_http_failure, currRecord.dashboard_name, "Error Message");
    helper.writeFailedRecordToRetryCSV(currRecord)
    failCount++;
    process.env.app_fail_count = failCount.toString(); 
  } else {
    passCount++;
    process.env.app_pass_count = passCount.toString();
  }
});
```

globalTeardown.ts

```
import logger from "./src/app.qualys.utils/logger";
import Helper from "./src/app.qualys.utils/helper";

async function globalTeardown() { 
  const helper = new Helper   
  const passCount = process.env.app_pass_count; 
  const failCount = process.env.app_fail_count; 
  logger.info(`Total passes: ${passCount} Total failure: ${failCount}`)
  helper.sendSummaryNotification(process.env.app_job_notify_http_summary, passCount, failCount);
}

export default globalTeardown;
```

environment variables:

```
app_pass_count = ""
app_fail_count = ""
```

I expect the passCount and failCount to be updated and correctly retrieved in the teardown file. However, the counts appear to be "empty" even though some tests have passed.

I've tried using process.env to set and access the counts, as well as using a helper class. I've also verified that the test.afterEach hook is updating the counts correctly during the test run.